# Can the following linear program have a negative optimal solution?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

Can the following linear program have a negative optimal solution?
$$\max \ x_{m+1}$$
$$a_{i}^{T}x+x_{m+1}\leq b_{i} \hspace{5mm},i=1,\dots,n$$
$$x=(x_{1},\dots,x_m)^{T}\in \mathbb{R}^m,x_{m+1}\in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: I noticed that it 's kind of related to piecewise linear programs but I couldn't conclude to anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, for $m=1$ and
\begin{eqnarray}
x+x_2&\le&-1,\\
-x+x_2&\le&-1
\end{eqnarray}
will make $x_2\le -1-|x|$ with the optimal value $\max x_2=-1$.